# BD para distribuição junto com aplicação java

Tags: java, hsqldb, banco-de-dados

Boa noite galera, tenho uma pequena aplicação JAVA em que são inseridos alguns dados. Gostaria de distribuí-la com um SGBD que não necessite de download e instalação/configuração.

Andei pesquisando e achei o HSQLDB, porém li em alguns locais que se o banco de dados for distribuído dentro do JAR ele será somente para leitura. Há alguma forma de disponibilizar o banco junto com o aplicativo e que permita a inserção de dados? Caso não seja possível, existe algum que suporte isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qualquer que seja o seu banco de dados, ele precisará salvar os dados da aplicação em algum lugar do seu disco rígido. Arquivos JAR não foram projetados para serem modificados enquanto estão sendo lidos ou executados, eles foram projetados para serem lidos e executados. E mesmo se fosse possível fazer isso com os arquivos JAR, isso teria que ser uma capacidade especial do SGBD.

Por causa disso, recomendo bancos de dados que salvem as informações em arquivos locais. Destes posso citar o HSQLDB, o H2, o Derby e o Firebird, pois eles dispensam a necessidade de instalação. Acho que o SQLite também pode servir (não tenho certeza). Devem existir outros.

Entretanto, novamente venho a frisar que qualquer um que você utilizar vai precisar ser capaz de realizar escrita e modificação de arquivos no disco.

Por fim, não há problema em distribuir o seu SGBD dentro do JAR. O problema está em você tentar salvar os dados dentro desse mesmo JAR.

Comment: Obrigado! Se é possível distribuir algum desses SGBDs que citou na mesma pasta do JAR e for possível inserir e recuperar dados pelo código do JAR , então meu problema está resolvido!

Answer (score 3):

Sim, se você distribuir o banco de dados dentro do jar, será somente leitura, porém, existem bancos como [**HSQLDB**](http://hsqldb.org/) E [**SQLite**](https://www.sqlite.org/), que criam arquivos referentes a banco de dados externo ao seu jar, no mesmo diretório ou em outro que você definir, se você ler [**aqui**](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch01.html#N100F3)  verá que o hsldb cria seu banco de dados em um arquivo `.script` e  o [**sqlite cria um arquivo**](https://www.sqlite.org/quickstart.html) com extensão `.db`.

Existem inúmeros tutoriais ensinando como manipular tais bancos, até a própria documentação do banco é material de consulta. Recomendo [**este tutorial**](http://www.guj.com.br/content/articles/hsqldb/hsqldb_guj.pdf), caso opte pelo HSQLDB, apesar de um pouco antigo, ele te dará uma base boa para iniciar a codificação e modelagem do banco.

Comment: Obrigado! Se é possível distribuir algum desses SGBDs que citou na mesma pasta do JAR e for possível inserir e recuperar dados pelo código do JAR , então meu problema está resolvido!

Answer (score 1):

Dentro do seu jar só vai o driver do banco de dados.

No seu programa você vai mandar ele criar um banco externamente. Pode ser na mesma pasta do jar, ou em um caminho comum como o disco C: (em caso de Windows, mas não recomendo) ou na pasta de usuário (mais recomendado). O importante é ser uma pasta que você tem permissão de escrita.

Você pode criar dados iniciais se necessário ou já distribuir o banco inicial junto com seu sistema.

Isso vale para os vários bancos citados como HSQLDB, Derby, H2 e Firebird

Comment: Obrigado! Se é possível distribuir algum desses SGBDs que citou na mesma pasta do JAR e for possível inserir e recuperar dados pelo código do JAR , então meu problema está resolvido!

Comment: É possível sim.